# Negation of an inequality

Tags: logic, order-theory, decision-theory

Working on semi orders, for a binary relation $R$ on a set $A$ we have that it is a semi order if the following holds

$$
aRb\longleftrightarrow u(a)\geq u(b) + q
$$

For $q\geq 0$ and $u : A \to\mathbb{R}$.

Then it is written in my book that

> $\neg(aRb)$ is equivalent to

$$
u(a)<u(b) - q
$$

> 

Whereas I was thinking of just $u(a)<u(b)+q$.

Have you some explanations to provide on this please ?

Comment: Can you please quote here exactly what your book says? Precision of expression is critical in math.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum  Thank you for your comment, it’s done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. The negation of a statement $x \geq y$ for any $x,y\in\bf R$ is $x<y$.

Now the **dual**, $a R^d b$, of the statement is another thing. It’s defined so that $a R^d b$ precisely when $b R a$. Thus, for example, $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ are dual to one another. And for your example where $aRb$ is defined in terms of $u$ and $q$ to mean $u(a)\geq u(b)+q$, the dual is of course $u(a) \leq u(b)-q$. But even that is not (quite) what your book said the negation is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !